# Intent in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kotlin

Why can't I just write class.`kotlin` instead of writing class.java.
Because `AndroidMeActivity` is a kotlin class and I am getting an error `("Unsoloved refrence: java")` when I write this,

How can I fix it.

```
 val intent = Intent(this, AndroidMeActivity::class.java)
```

Comment: Do you have the Kotlin standard library in your Gradle dependencies?

Comment: What is it? can you write off the code.

Answer (score 1):

> "Unsoloved refrence: java"

Read [**`Reflection`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references)

> Reflection is a set of language and library features that allows for
>   introspecting the structure of your own program at runtime.

Make sure, You added **`org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin`**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    ext.gradle_version = '3.0.1'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

And check you added below in your module level **`build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Java platform, the runtime component required for using the reflection features is distributed as a separate JAR file `(kotlin-reflect.jar)`. This is done to reduce the required size of the runtime library for applications that do not use reflection features. If you do use reflection, please make sure that the .jar file is added to the classpath of your project.

see link https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references

Answer (score 0):

if your AndroidMeActivity class is java class then used below code ..

```
        val intent=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
```

if you are used android studio 3.0 above then is working if below then you can add kotlin plugins in android studio and setup configratution.

i suggest you can update your android studio 3.0 above is automatically supported kotlin.
then after any new project start it provide include kotlin option in dialog where define you app name.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use intent like this.

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_login);
button.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(this, OTPActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```